# Mac OS doesn't spin down drive despite fstab

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, fstab

I have a drive which has 2 partitions (GUID):

```
macOS - Data -> HFS
Windows - Data -> NTFS
```

I don't want to have those partitions mounted by default so I added them on fstab to ignore them on boot like this:

```
UUID=34939209-6C36-3DB1-ABCE-1ADBE84B2F63 none hfs rw,noauto  
UUID=D755C1DE-EC4A-4CE6-BD82-89BAA3121B4C none ntfs rw,noauto
```

The partition are not mounted however the drive still spins up and doesn't spin down until 5 to 10min. How can I get the disk to immediatly spin down ?

diskutil output:

```
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨Windows - Data⁩          475.7 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Mac - Data⁩              524.2 GB   disk2s3
```

Comment: NTFS volumes *do* have a UUID, accessed the same way as HFS+ `diskutil info VolumeName`. Use the Volume UUID not the Partition UUID. To prevent mount, you can use a generic `none auto noauto` for any volume type.

Comment: Hmm. checking my own fstab I just noticed I do have one Win volume that I accidentally used the disk/part UUID & it still works. BTW, I don't know if doing this will prevent spinup - it might have to spin up to be recognised, then it will go back to sleep once its internal timer runs down.

Comment: So I checked and indeed diskutil info gave me the correct UUID. I replaced the label with UUID dans it still doesn't mount (as expected). However this doesn't solve the fact that the drive doesn't spin down. I also think that it's normal that it spins up the first time to be able to read the UUIDs but then it should quickly spin down as it's not used. The only way I found is to do `diskutil eject disk2` manually but this is not really optimal. Maybe this is expected behaviour...